# How to hide sub categories in sidebar

Tags: sidebar

i want to hide subcategories  in widget sidebar . just in widget sidebar
i was added in style.css this code

```
.children { display:none;}
```

but this code do hide to the threaded comments

what is the way to hide just sub categories in sidebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give us markup so I can't know if this is correct but

```
.sidebar .children { display:none;}
```

EDIT:
I think you're looking to hide your .commentlist .children correct? Line 1460-1463 of your file are the .children selector. try making each of them

```
ol.commentlist li ul.children li.depth-2 { margin:0 0 3px; display:none}
ol.commentlist li ul.children li.depth-3 { margin:0 0 3px; display:none}
ol.commentlist li ul.children li.depth-4 { margin:0 0 3px; display:none}
ol.commentlist li ul.children li.depth-5 { margin:0 0 3px; display:none}
```

Is this a widget in your sidebar? I can't tell without the markup, you only gave the .css. What is the link to your website?

Comment: .sidebar .children { display:none;} its not work

Comment: thanks man now its work with this code .sidebar_content  .children { display:none;}

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it friend.